# Best Practise listening to Cookie Changed Event in React / NextJs

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js, react-state-management

Disclaimer:
This is for learning purposes and not a real project, if what I am trying to achieve makes no sense, feel free to point that out.

What I want to do:

If the user visits my website, he has to accept cookies.
If he tries to signup, but has not yet accepted the cookies, signup is not possible and there will be a message hinting at this.

What I have done so far:

I installed a third-party library to display a cookie-consent banner on entering the website.

```
import CookieConsent from 'react-cookie-consent'
```

To guarantee that the consent-banner shows up everywhere, I added the `CookieConsent`-component inside my `_app.js` file, which is used whenever a page is intialized. This works fine, I can see the cookie-banner whereever I go, until I accept the cookie.

Now here is where I am uncertain of how to address this properly.
How do listen to a change of my `CookieConsent` (which is created by the above mentioned 3rd party library, it has a boolean value inside)?
When I am in control of my component, I always use `useState` and, if needed, `useEffect`.
But this time, the value of a cookie doesn't get changed by a react-hook, so listening to a change / re-rendering of a page won't work.

So yeah, that's pretty much the question: What is the proper way to do this?

All I can come up with in my mind is to create my own cookie-component and add subscriber/observer events there. But this seems like a bad approach, because then I had to create my own components for CookieConsent and CookieRetrieval, therefore re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Hey Leviathan, did you find any solution for this? I'm stuck with it as well.

Comment: Hey, sadly no. I haven't really worked on that any more. But looking at the question right now, I guess what I would suggest you to try is using React's Context feature.